# Rebuilding exisiting linux kernel on hardware(microzed zynq)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fpga, zynq

I have xillinux OS (based on ubunutu 12.04.LTS) installed on my hardware (ZYNQ FPGA Board). I have done some hardware reconfiguration and I need to rebuild my kernel after editing the config-3.12.0-xillinux-1.3 file. My question is how do I rebuild the existing kernel on the hardware after making changes to the config file

http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Uartlite+Driver

This is the page above that I am referring to where they say that:

To enable the uartlite driver in the linux kernel you either have to integrate it or build it as kernel module (.ko). You can enable it with:

```
make menuconfig
---> Device Drivers ---> Character devices ---> Serial drivers ---> Xilinx uartlite serial port support
```

make menuconfig - I have to enter this command on the OS running on my hardware in the /root/boot/.config folder  to enable it ?

What does , ---> Device Drivers ---> Character devices ---> Serial drivers ---> Xilinx uartlite serial port support THIS MEAN ? I have to change directory ?

The other option as per the link posted above is to add certain lines as below to the config file, for which I would use the nano editor and then save it with ctrl+X and then Y.

```
# integrate into the kernel
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE=y
# build as loadable module
CONFIG_SERIAL_UARTLITE=m
```

But they say that, "After that you of course have to rebuild the kernel and deploy it to your Zynq device."

Where zynq is the hardware I am running my OS on. What commands do I have to use to rebuild the existing kernel on my hardware after making changes to the .config file ?

So, after rebuilding the kernel with the changes above, I just reboot to observer the changes ?

EDIT:

I was referring to this link, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/...-linux-kernel/

So, in order to compile the exisiting kernel on the hadrware and build it, I edit the .config file using nano in /boot folder and save it.
Then, I type "make" in the same folder as config.
Then, I type "make modules" in the same folder
Then I type make modules_install Then I type make install
Then I reboot the system to see the new kernel installed.
Is this the right way of doing it ?

Is this how you recompiled and rebuilt it ?

Currently in my boot directory, there are 4 files.
One config file and 3 .dts files. After rebuilding the kernel, this might change ?

Comment: Firstly, you need to download [kernel sources](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Fetch+Sources) to some Linux machine, which has compiler. Other steps (configuring: `make menuconfig`, building: `make` and so on) you should perform in the kernel sources top-dir.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I dont want to download the kernel sources to a different linux machine. I want to recompile the existing  kernel on the existing OS running on the existing hardware,  which already has a compiler on it. This way I dont have to install sources or cross compile.The link to my OS, http://xillybus.com/downloads/doc/xillybus_getting_started_zynq.pdf
If you see section 6.3 there is the compiling part. I want to modify the .config file in /boot folder, save it. And then use the commands in this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/ . Does this sound right ?

Comment: For build *out-of-tree module*, it is sufficient to have headers(and some other files), corresponded to the running kernel(section 6.3 describes that). But for *modify kernel itself*, such as change configuration, you need to build kernel from sources. Probably, you can do that on the board itself, but you need to build from sources in any case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev SO, I need to do a git clone on the same device of the orginal directory ( git clone git://github.com/), then make. uimage and uboot file generated.

Comment: Directory, which is target for `git clone`, can be any (and better to be **not** under `/boot`). Actually, wiki describes how to [build kernel](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Build+kernel), how to [prepare boot image](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Prepare+Boot+Image) and some other steps.

Comment: If you have your driver built-in before and want to rebuild as a module you have to rebuild kernel as well, and thus all the rest modules.